# Interchangeable API root url

Tags: reactjs, webpack, gulp, backend

I have a project handled by Webpack and Gulp. All the API's use a singular ROOT_URL variable and append strings to fetch information from the backend.

For multiple deployments I have different back end servers serving from different databases. Currently for each update I have to change the ROOT_URL and bundle the project in each individual server.

Ideally I would like to just pass a bundle to each deployed server so that each one will reference a local JS file containing their respective ROOT_URLs. Is there a way to do this and/or is there an industry standard?

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you have a something that varies by server generally you would use environmental variables.  If you need it in your javascript spa's you will have to pass the environmental variable from your server to your javascript(possibly through a templating engine like ejs if your using node). Ultimately how to do this depends on what backend technologies your using.

Answer (score 0):

With Webpack you can specify the config file location. I use this to have separate `dev` and `production` configs. You could use this to have a separate config file for each environment that handles updating the ROOT_URL for you.

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --config ./src/config/dev.config.js",
    "prod": "webpack --config ./src/config/prod.config.js"
  },
```

Comment: My question is more towards deployment. All my apis use a ROOT_URL variable that determines the backend address (aka which db to use). Currently in the setup I have to go to each deployment server, change the ROOT_URL to the appropriate address, then build the project for distribution. Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: I'm confused as to where your ROOT_URL variable is stored and being set? In the front-end somewhere, the server or a backend database.yml?

Comment: It is in a root_url.jsx file within the project

Comment: Can you post that file in the example? There really are a ton of different ways to achieve what you want, but it's hard without knowing how your system works.

Answer (score 0):

You can define environment variables using Webpack's DefinePlugin

Imagine you have a deployment script `npm run deploy`

In your `webpack.config.js` add a `DefinePlugin`

```
module.exports = {
  entry: 'app.js',
  plugins: [
     new webpack.DefinePlugin({
       'process.env.API_ROOT': JSON.stringify(process.env.API_ROOT)
     })
  ]
}
```

Then in your code:

`api.js`

```
var url = process.env.API_ROOT + '/resource'
fetch(url).then(function(){
  // do stuff
})
```

Then when you deploy you can define different API roots

`API_ROOT=https://api1.com npm run deploy` (will deploy code with API 1)

`API_ROOT=https://api2.com npm run deploy` (will deploy code with API 2)

.. and so forth. Webpack will automatically replace all the occurrences of `process.env.API_ROOT` in your code with the correct URL.

Comment: Would this solution require Webpack to create a new bundle?

Comment: Yes each deployment would be a new build.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution so that the webpack can reference an outside file. That way each server could have different Root Url file and I would only have to deploy the same bundle to all instances